# iOS/iPad Force Input American QUERTY keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, internationalization, keyboard

First Post - so be kind...

I have an iPad app that has many text entry fields. I would like to 
only have **QWERTY** Keyboard input into my application, **but**, 
unfortunately, when I change to another language (e.g.: **arabic**) 
the standard **QWERTY** keyboard characters is NOT available.

I should note that it seems that one field **does** force the **QWERTY** 
Keyboard display when it is active:  Password field for my app).

Yes, I can filter the input after it gets into my application (which 
is what I am doing right now), but I would prefer to force the user 
to use the QWERTY keyboard for all input?

So, to repeat the question:

Is there a way to force all my text entry boxes to have the same attributes
   for input as the password text field - and thus forcing all of my input to 
   be **QWERTY** based?

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot change anything about `UIKeyboard` out side of the options allowed by `UITextView` and `UITextField`.  That means that having the field be a password field, shows the clear button, etc are the only options you're allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This seems like you should be able to!

Comment: @Tom I know it would seem like, it but look at the documentation for `UIKeyboard`.  I'll give you a hint, there isn't any.  The keyboard is sandboxed from the app just as your app is sandboxed from other apps.

Comment: @Tom And just so if you're asking future questions, its spelled QWERTY. :)

Comment: yep, it was in the body of the text, but I forgot to change subject line!